# Добавить строки с помощью batchupdate sheets api

Tags: google-sheets-api

Подскажите, пожалуйста , как можно добавить новые строки с помощью batchupdate? Листал документацию, там ид листа, rows , length . Но при выполнении ошибка типа ожидалось 2-3 аргумента. К сожалению, с телефона, не могу скрин сделать и подвесить. Может просто кто уже добавлял так?

Comment: batchUpdate

{
  "requests": [
    {
      "appendDimension": {
        "sheetId": sheetId,
        "dimension": "ROWS",
        "length": 3
      }
    },
    {
      "appendDimension": {
        "sheetId": sheetId,
        "dimension": "COLUMNS",
        "length": 1
      }
    }
  ]
}

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте метод InsertDimensionRequest
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#insertdimensionrequest